# bloginfo() executing out of order?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code in my WordPress header.php file. It is for printing a dynamic title in HTML:

```
<title>
    <?php if (is_page_template('page-home.php')){
    echo 'Home - ' . 
    bloginfo('name');
    }
</title>
```

The rendered HTML looks like this:

```
<title>My Cool BlogHome - </title>
```

I believe it should look like this:

```
<title>Home - My Cool Blog</title>
```

My question is: Why does the echo and bloginfo() execution seem to be reversed? My echoed text seems to be printing after bloginfo().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [get_bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) instead.

`bloginfo()` runs, and immediately echos out when it's called. `get_bloginfo()` returns a value, which you can then include in your echo statement.

Currently, `bloginfo` is printing out a value out as soon as it's called; then `echo` statement is echoed out.